# Scraping/Parse URL for Images

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, parsing, swift

So I would like to Scrap a URL to get all IMG-Tags from the HTML in iOS.

Are there any Librarys that can scrap a URL for HTML-Tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Ono](https://github.com/mattt/Ono), an Objective-C library for parsing XML and HTML.

Comment: Did you used it yourself??

Answer (score 0):

You can check [WebScraper](https://github.com/laiso/WebScraper-iOS) for iOS.